# How to rectify heteroscedasticity for multiple linear regression model

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I'm fitting a multiple linear regression model with 6 predictiors (3 continuous and 3 categorical). The residuals vs. fitted plot show that there is heteroscedasticity, also it's confirmed by bptest().

[summary of sales_lm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xze6Y.png)

[rediduals vs. fitted plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3Ru.png)

Also I calculated the sqrt for my train data and test data, as showed below:

```
sqrt(mean(sales_train_lm_pred-sales_train$SALES)^2)
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3Ru.png) 3533.665

```
 sqrt(mean(sales_test_lm_pred-sales_test$SALES)^2)
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3Ru.png) 3556.036

I tried to fit glm() model, but still didn't rectify heteroscedasticity.

```
 glm.test3<-glm(SALES~.,weights=1/sales_fitted$.resid^2,family=gaussian(link="identity"), data=sales_train)
```

[resid vs. fitted plot for glm.test3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmIx8.png)
it looks weird. 
[glm.test3 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjYP8.png)

Could you please help me what should I do next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first suggestion is to transform your data in `log` scale and perform the same analyses. The second is to take the first-order difference and perform the same analyses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you observe heteroscedasticity for your data means that the variance is not stationary.  You can try the following:

1) Apply the one-parameter [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) (of the which the log transform is a special case) with a suitable `lambda` to one or more variables in the data set.  The optimal `lambda` can be determined by looking at its log-likelihood function. Take a look at `MASS::boxcox`.

2) Play with your feature set (decrease, increase, add new variables).

2) Use the weighted linear regression method.

Comment: Many thanks both of you, I tried transforming my data in log scale, Box-Cox transformation, also decrease/increase variables, but don't work for my data. Next I will try to use the weighted linear regression method. I'm novice and trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Aifen No problem. If you liked the answer, consider upvoting or accepting.